# Is there a way to leave the resolution of a C# Windows Form Application fixed?

Tags: c#

I want to fix the resolution of my main form, I can set the number of pixels using

```
 this.Height = 480;
 this.Width = 640;
```

But I want some way to make it constant, so that even if the frame is enlarged, the number of pixels will not change, but their size.

By setting the option `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink` I can prevent re-sizing of the form by dragging the edges of the form, but when the maximize button is pressed, the form becomes big and adds new pixels. I want to allow the re-sizing of the form and putting it in maximized or fullscreen mode without changing the number of pixels in the form, or in other words, enlarging the size if the current pixels, instead of adding new pixels.

Is there a way too do it?

Comment: winforms doesn't allow resolution independence without resorting to a bunch of horrible hacks. If you need real resolution independence you will have to use WPF.

Comment: You could simply change the form's Font property.

Comment: @HansPassant, please expand on this.

Comment: I can't be heard over the WPF shouting anymore.  Just try it, the built-in autoscaling also works in the designer.  Change the form's Font property and give it a larger size.  And note how everything auto-scales proportionally.

Comment: @HansPassant, I really don't know what you mean so I can't "just try it", If you post an answer and it'll work without changing to WPF, I'll accept it. or at least put a link to an example or an explanation. I just want to emphesise that I'm not talking just about text, but mainly about shapes drawn to the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pixels are fixed units. You probably would like WPF since its a vector based system.